# Devo declarar Get's e Set's na UML?

Tags: uml, getters-setters

Sempre que vou criar um UML de classe tenho que declarar `get` e `set` para todas as classes que venha utilizá-los ou posso deixar sem, como se ele fosse padrão e todos soubessem que devem implementá-los mesmo não estando no UML?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O mais importante é sempre ser consistente. Isto inclui ser consistente com o que a equipe faz.

Se a equipe ainda vai definir o que fazer eu apenas indicaria que existem métodos de acesso de forma genérica bastando uma linha indicando isto.

Nem todo mundo concorda com isto especialmente se estes métodos incluem alguma lógica relevante, o que de uma certa forma o torna um método como outro qualquer.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: e quando o construtor realiza as operações do setters, como declaro o construtor ?

Comment: Normalmente ele é criado como os primeiros métodos da classe. Mas note que não existem regras fixas, não tem certo ou errado, escolha uma forma e seja consistente.

Answer (score 0):

Sempre mantive os SET/GET de forma implícita ao Diagrama de Classe, por exemplo.

Mas eu acho que depende, a forma que o professor deseja que seja feito, ou até mesmo a equipe de desenvolvimento. Eu sempre tive uma briga com UML, uma vez que diversas pessoas tem ideias, conceitos e métodos diferentes para aplicações de atributos nos Diagramas.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo não estaria errado mas..... considero que deve manter um certo nível de abstração no uml, por uma simples razão, quase ngm cria get set na mão(recurso de ide), e vc já sabe que necessita deles, então vai ser um desperdiço  de tempo, e espaço no uml, pra uma coisa que ja esta impregnada no seu subconsciente, o uml é pra você não se perder no projeto. mas se tem ciência que precisa do getset, não tem necessidade de colocar.